# schema.org- structured data for video sharing website

Tags: rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets, structured-data, google-index

I have added the following code to my website, is video sharing website

```
        <div itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/videoobject">
        <h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="name">{$video_data.video_title}</h1>
        <meta itemprop="duration" content="{$video_data.iso8601_duration}" />
        <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="{$video_data.thumb_img_url}" />
        <meta itemprop="contentURL" content="url/videos.php?vid={$video_data.uniq_id}"/>
        <meta itemprop="embedURL" content="{$video_data.embed_href}" />
        <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="{$video_data.html5_datetime}" /> >
```

The problem that google has removed my website from organic search to video search.
Is change the video object to website the right decision ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that's not exactly the *wrong* behavior, just undesired.  My guess is that you'd be better off with it as a video (unless you've seen a noticeable hit already).  That being said, changing it back to 'website' or something like that may or may not work.